# Why does Pinchas come to the Bris?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle, brit-milah, pinchas, eliyahu-hanavi

Why does  Pinchas who is Eliyahu Hanavi (Elijah the Prophet) come to Brissim and what does it have to do with this  Parshas Pinchas?

Comment: The question is written as a riddle (i.e., like the question knows the answer already. There's really no other reason I can think of for asking what it has to do with the _parasha_ rather than asking whether it has anything to do with the _parasha_). Closing per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140.

Comment: @msh210 If the 2nd part of the question is the problem, why not just edit it out. The 1st part of the question looks valid and constructive.

Comment: @yydl, even the first part: _Eliyahu_ is known for coming. Asking why "Pinchas who is Eliyahu" comes rather than asking why _Eliyahu_ comes implies that the questioner already has a reason in mind for _Pinchas_.

Comment: @msh210 Hmm, so if someone comes along and asks why Eliyahu comes to Brissim, would that be a dup, or okay?

Comment: Sounds okay to me. You think this question should be reworded "why does _Eliyahu_ come to a _b'ris_" and reopened and the answer reworded "Because he's _Pin'chas_ and..."? What do others think?

Comment: Just scroll down. He answered it himself - and his answer was chosen as the best answer - less than an hour after posting the question. It was a riddle through and through.

Comment: @Seth You're judging the content based on context. I agree that the original question was phrased as a riddle, but the content itself is not. The question is do we edit it, and keep it, or ignore it and treat it as non-existent. I think the former is a better course of action.

Comment: @yydl I agree that editing and re-opening is a valid course of action if you feel that the question is valuable enough. The main point of closure, as opposed to deletion, is to give the author and others a chance to rehabilitate the question in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Bnei Yissochar** answers it says in Parshas Pinchas:

> תחת אשר **קנא** לאלוהיו ויכפר על בני ישראל

In Pirkie D'rav Eliezer it says:

> Hashem saw Pinchas and asked him "What are you doing?" he answered and said he was angry for Hashem and Hashem told him you are always angry for Hashem in Shitim about the Immorality and here on the fact that they wait until you see the Bris with your own eyes.From Here we Have the Minhag to put a Chair for Eliyahu at every Bris as he is called the Angel of Circumcision.

The Bnei Yissochar said he heard of a Medrash on this where Eliyahu continues and tells Hashem what will be if I will be at the Bris of a sinner I wont be able to withstand him. Hashem answered and said I will forgive him.He went further and said what if the guests are sinners Hashem replied I will forgive them also,He went further and said maybe the Mohel will be a sinner Hashem answered I will forgive him too.

Now we can explain the Possuk:
"תחת אשר קינא לאלוקיו"-Because you are zealous for Hashem.
"קנאי לה'"-Therfore you can not stand sinners
"ויכפר על בני ישראל" –Therfore all of the Jews will be forgiven.

Therefore he comes to Brissim to bear witness to Hashem's promise to grant everyone forgiveness, and the posuk in Parshas Pinchas explains why Hashem grants us this forgivness.

Comment: YS, you accidentaly wrote that Eliyahu comes to Brissim to grant everyone forgiveness. It is Hashem that does the forgiving, Eliyahu (Pinchas) who does the testifying.

Comment: Thanx, for correcting me I don't want to be Catholic or anything.